# Event Tracking in google analytics

Tags: php, html, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to have track all Ajax requests coming to my web page.
Is it possible using event tracking in google analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Google will track any page whose scripts get executed.  So if your page gets requested by a client that isn't executing any of the javascript, like a data miner, that request will not be detected by google since google's script was never executed.  If you want to track all requests, you can check your server logs or use php or some other server-side scripting language to log the request in a file or database.

Comment: Currently we use PHP and insert records in database. But there are millions of hits on the server and database is becoming so large.

Comment: If you have a high volume site you could very well end up with huge tables.  There are a number of ways you can optimize a tracking system but indexing is the first stop.  If you got crap indexes, a few changes and you could experience vast improvements.